# Lineup captions of figures horizontally

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

[image: Example image of table caption's lineup]

I got these three figures side-by-side. All of the figures are in different sizes and I got different number of lines of text in the caption for each of the figures. My problem is that I want all of the captions (first row of the captions, "Figure 1:", "Figure 2:", "Figure 3:") to be lined up horizontally. 
***I put in an example image.**

I know that with tables I'am able to use [t] as table-captions are above the table, but figure-captions are below the figure and by that it suddenly becomes alot harder for me to solve the problem as I'm not able to use [b].

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{f01.jpg}
            \caption{Myyyy teeeexxxxt}
            \label{f04}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.02\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{f02.jpg}
            \caption{My texty texttext}
            \label{f01}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.02\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{f03.jpg}
            \caption{Textytex[![enter image description here][1]][1]t of my text which is text}
            \label{f03}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using a floating environment like `figure` inside a `minibox` environment does not make sense.  The way around makes sense.

`caption.sty` provides an undocumented macro `\captionbox` which comes handy for your use case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{caption,graphicx,geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par
  \vspace{1ex}
  \fbox{%
    \captionbox{Some caption text which is not so
      long\label{fig:one}}[.45\textwidth][c]{%
      \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
    }%
  }%
  \hfill
  \fbox{%
    \captionbox{Some caption text which is now longer and therefore
      has more text\label{fig:two}}[.45\textwidth][c]{%
      \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{1ex}
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Cheat! `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\caption{This is a short caption on two lines}
\end{minipage}

\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{example-image-b}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\caption{This is a long caption on three lines, I hope
this text suffices for the task at hand.}
\end{minipage}

\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `minipage` is bottom aligned, but its bottom is the top of the caption!

[image]